# How can I do FaceBook login with django rest framework without requiring the client to use a popup?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, facebook-oauth, python-social-auth

So, I've setup an auth system using djoser and rest-social-auth ( https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth )

but it seems it requires the client to open a pop-up or modal to login with facebook, which our frontend dev says is a bad idea, we should use server-side redirects instead.

So - assuming this is sensible - how do I go about the serverside setup to skip the facebook modal on client side? I'm happy to swap out the current social auth lib with something else if it makes things easier.

FWIW - we are using angular on frontend, but are also planning on other frontends in the future

Comment: There’s the server-side login flow, that works by redirecting the user inside the existing tab/window – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow – whether or not django has that already implemented, or if you’ll need to do some coding yourself, I don’t know.

Comment: is the client a browser or a mobile phone app?

Answer (score 3):

The client side authorization with the JavaScript SDK is the easiest one, and it is perfectly safe. It´s also the best one for the user, because you do not need to redirect to a login page. Not sure why your frontend dev says it´s a bad idea, it´s actually the best and recommended way. The popup is ok in that case, because it is initiated by the user. Here´s an example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

After authorization, you can send the Access Token to the server, in case you need it there. Make sure you read this though, and use `appsecret_proof`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

You can easily put the code in an Angular service, for example.

Comment: Well, his exact words were:

    "we can't use fb sdk js
    because modals can be blocked"

Comment: that´s what i thought - it does not matter in this case, at least not if you do it right. i am using ad blockers in my browsers, and they do not block the fb login popup > because it´s user initated. just make sure you follow the example from my answer, only use FB.login directly on user interaction.

Comment: in fact, i am using the js sdk since many years for this, and never had problems with the login popup. also, the base code did not change a bit in all those years, it´s mainly the same as some years ago - while the php sdk changed a LOT. :)